# rails sending multiple emails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, email

I am trying to send multiple emails to multiple brands. I have tried to make a loop that runs through this multiple times while changing the email of the mail recipient but it will only send to the last mail request. How would I go about solving this? here is my current code:

```
@user_products.each do |p|
  @brands << p.brand
end
count = 0
@brands = @brands.uniq
while count < @brands.count
    debugger
        @brand = @brands[count]
            mail(to: @brands[count].email, subject: 'A purchase has been made!' )
            count += 1
    end
```

My html code to get the products on made by the certain brand:

```
<body style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #d55d5d; width: 75%;">
    <div align="center">
        <img src="http://localhost:3000/assets/motobanner-d2fde8a6e30060905a6f72b0c8128d222a7596e690a7a4c648e5e81109bf4600.jpg" style="margin-top: 0% ;width: 75%; height: 240px;" ></img>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Hello, <%= @brand.name %>!</h2>
            <p style="font-size: 1.2em;">There has been a purchase of the following items:</p>
            <% @user_products.each do |item| %>
                <div align="center"> <%= image_tag "http://localhost:3000/#{item.picture.url}", alt: item.product_name if item.picture && item.brand_id == @brand.id %><br /></div>
                <b><%= "Product name:" if item.brand_id == @brand.id %></b> <%= item.product_name if item.brand_id == @brand.id %>
                <b><%= "Product description:" if item.brand_id == @brand.id %></b><br /> <p class="product-description"><%= item.product_description if item.brand_id == @brand.id %></p>
                <b><%= "Product price:" if item.brand_id == @brand.id %></b> <%= "£" + item.product_price.to_s if item.brand_id == @brand.id %>
            <% end %>
</body>
```

The debugger for my email is there as I ran through the loop and it ran the `mail(to: @brands[count].email, subject: 'A purchase has been made!' )` line every time it looped which is why I fail to understand why it does not work.

Comment: If i'm remembering it right, the mail object has a send method.
What I suppose is happening is that you're effectively building all those mails but rails only sends the last one for you since it is the one that is returned last.

Comment: Ah I see, would there be a better way to performing this action?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the looping outside the the mailer, as in official example:

```
class SendWeeklySummary
  def run
    User.find_each do |user|
      UserMailer.weekly_summary(user).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html
and you are probably missing the deliver_now part (can be replaced by deliver_later and performed by worker process